# Book where humans were engineered with genes from animal species to survive hostile planets

Tags: story-identification

This was asked elsewhere but the querent has never been back. It has, however, got me very curious as to the answer. 
Please note: I can't answer anything on the content as I'm not the OP

> looking for this book had humans genetically engineered with different animals genes to withstand harsh planets after leaving earth one race was mixed with black bears and were called bors.
>   there were races mixed with otter a race called tarbek which had poisonus breath.
>   races mixed with polar bears for harsher colder planets

Comment: How will you know if the answer is correct?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - It's unlikely that there will be another book about genetically engineered animals called bors and tarbeks, unless it's a sequel

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to be Stepwater by [L. Warren Douglas](http://lwarrendouglas.com/). According to [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/64764.Stepwater):

> In a time when genengineered humans inhabit alien worlds, the bors,
>   humans with bear genes, and the mantee, a human/otter mix, reach the
>   brink of war when a man and a woman break the strongest taboo of their
>   clans--and only the Arbiter has the answer.

From the book:

> Tarbeks' sulphurous metabolisms seemed unearthly, but who knew what
>   genes they owed to bacteria that lived in undersea volcanic vents?

And:

> There lay a city, Nort, occupied by wends, mantees, fards, and the
>   occasional tarbek.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have posted the answer on the other site (with credit to Stack Exchange, Raj and Valorum). If ever the OP returns and confirms then I'll accept here....is that okay or should I accept now?

Comment: @DannyMcG Well... I kinda disagree. Your question was for a book about genetically engineered animals called bors and tarbeks. _You_ asked the question, and _you_ got an answer. It's all _yours_ in that sense, there would be nothing wrong with _you_ accepting it. First, as Valorum said, "_It's unlikely that there will be another_". Second, if _that other guy somewhere else_ now says "oh no, I actually remembered it wrong, it was about _Orbs_ and _Barteks_", what are you gonna do then? Kick this perfectly valid answer here?

Comment: That makes sense I s'pose . Okay I'll tick it